# How to code with excel vba to click a button on website that has no id, name, or class?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the html for the button:

```
<div style = "position:absolute;top:2px;left:5px;"> == $0  
  <button title = "Start New Quote" style = "background-color: 
  rgb(4,61,111);   
  color:rgb(255,255,255); width:122px;height:33px;padding-  
  left:0px;padding-right:0px;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;" onclick = 
  toggleNewBusinessMenu();   
  return false;"> == $0    
    <img style = "vertical-align: middle" src =  
      "/images/icons/create_quote.png"> == $0  
      "&nbsp;&nbspStart Quote&nbsp  
             "
 </button>  
 </div>
```

Here is one option I've tried but new at coding so not sure how its supposed to work with no name or id:

```
Sub Superior()
Dim ieApp As Object

'create a new instance of ie
Set ieApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ieApp.Visible = True

ieApp.navigate "website"

Wait 1
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

ieApp.document.all("login_email").Value = "username"
ieApp.document.all("login_password").Value = "password"
ieApp.document.all("login_button").Click

Wait 1
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

ieApp.document.getElementsByTagName("$0").Click

End Sub

Sub Wait(Seconds)
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "%COMSPEC% /c ping 127.0.0.1 -n " _
    & Seconds + 1, 0, True
End Sub
```

I have tried everything - thanks!

Comment: can you give the URL or share more light on the question and the details

Comment: For  VBA sake can you share the code that you have written and provide the URL? Please

Comment: I edited my post to clarify things and show you my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
Dim HTMLButton As Object
'etc
'
'
ieApp.document.all("login_email").Value = "username"
ieApp.document.all("login_password").Value = "password"
ieApp.document.all("login_button").Click

Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Wait 5

For Each HTMLButton In ieApp.document.getElementsByTagName("button")
    If HTMLButton.getAttribute("title") = "Start New Quote" Then
        HTMLButton.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next HTMLButton
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I actually tried that previously but still doesn't work :( not sure if I need to use the img src?

Comment: I'm not sure it would help, but try waiting 5 seconds, instead of 1 second, and try waiting after the ready state is complete instead of before.  I've edited my post.

Comment: Okay, I tried that. Its still not working. Do you know what else might work? Thanks!